# Terminar o último AsyncTask antes de começar outro

Tags: android, asynctask

Estou a usar um `AsyncTask` (App Android) para receber uma string `json` do servidor (Vem de um controller do meu site ASP MVC). 
Basicamente tudo que vem do servidor passa por esta classe

```
public class Communications extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     //vários caminhos aqui dentro
}
```

e no `onPostExecute` eu mando a informação onde é preciso e inicio diversas atividades (dependendo do que foi pedido ao servidor). O problema é quando a resposta demora e eu inicio mais um `AsyncTask` por cima. Como posso saber se há alguma tarefa a correr, e se estiver a correr, como cancela-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com a ajuda da resposta do utilizador @ramaral
Em baixo está o trecho de código que inicia todas as `AsyncTask`, e se estiver a correr a anterior ele cancela-a e começa a mais recente.

```
public class WebserviceJson {

  public static AsyncTask communicationTask;

  public static void callWebServiceJson(final Activity caller, String url, final String params) {
    final String[] parms = new String[3];
    parms[0] = url;
    parms[1] = params;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) caller.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(communicationTask == null){
            communicationTask = new Communications(caller).execute(parms);
        }
        else if(communicationTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)

            communicationTask = new Communications(caller).execute(parms);
        else {

            communicationTask.cancel(true);
            communicationTask = new Communications(caller).execute(parms);
```

Answer (score 5):

Por padrão as tarefas, criadas recorrendo à classe AsyncTask, são executadas sequencialmente num único *background thread*.

Para saber o estado de uma tarefa use o método [getStatus()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus()). Ele retorna um `enum` do tipo [AsyncTask.Status](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html), cujos valores são:

- `FINISHED` - Indica que a tarefa foi executada e o método `onPostExecute()` foi chamado e terminado.
- `PENDING` - Indica que a tarefa não foi ainda iniciada.
- `RUNNING` - Indica que a tarefa está em execução.

Para cancelar uma tarefa recorra ao método [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)).

Chamar este método resultará na chamada de `onCancelled()` após o retorno `doInBackground()`, garantindo que `onPostExecute()` nunca seja chamado.
No método `doInBackground()` deve ser periodicamente verificado o valor retornado por `isCancelled()` e, caso seja `true`, terminar a tarefa o mais cedo possível.